# Webform Touch Slide to next page

Tags: javascript, webforms, theming, mobile-tools

Is this possible?

I'm using the jQuery touch swipe module but it doesnt seem to work. The form I have is a 3 part form, with the next button allowing to go to the next page. I want to replace the next with a "swipe" to go back and forth to the pages. Is this possible?

jQuery Touch Swipe doesnt come with much in terms of documentation or installation.